# Inbox back button turns to toggle button

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

On the iOS app, you can open your inbox by pressing this button:

[image]

Which lets you view your notifications, etc. You can press 'back' to go back, indicated by the following arrow icon on the very left:

[image]

But if you **click an iOS notification from the notifications drag down**, which then opens your inbox, you get the toggle:

[image]

Which feels unnatural, because it acts acts the same as the toggle you see here, which is on the main page of whichever site you're on:

[image]

I know for a fact it didn't function like this in the past (I've used the app pretty rigorously).

**Is this a bug, or intended functionality?**

Comment: It's largely that I wasn't sure what behavior made sense.  I recently made a change where the inbox is pushed onto the navigation stack (with a back button) rather than presented over the screen (with a close button) when you tap the icon.  But what should we do for a notification?  I guess pushing on top of whatever's visible makes sense but there may not be an inbox icon in the previous screen so I just stuck it in its own thing.  I'll try it the other way to see how it feels.

Comment: @BrianNickel Well i'm only 1 person but after it happening about 20 times I can say i'm used to having a back button and it fees unnatural to have to find and click feed again or my name. It's just expected behavior and it surprises you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be changed in 1.5.3.3.

I'm switching the behavior so now it'll push the inbox on top of the navigation stack.  (Or pop back to it if you already have one in the stack.)